# Xelement.XPathSelectElement

Tags: c#, xpath, xelement

I have the following XPath String

```
"(//DEAL_SETS/DEAL_SET/DEALS/DEAL/PARTIES/PARTY[ROLES/ROLE/
    ROLE_DETAIL/PartyRoleType='Borrower'])  
        [(ROLES/PARTY_ROLE_IDENTIFIERS/PARTY_ROLE_IDENTIFIER/
            PartyRoleIdentifier='1' or position() = 1)]/ROLES/ROLE/BORROWER/
                RESIDENCES/RESIDENCE/ADDRESS/PostalCode[../../RESIDENCE_DETAIL/
                    BorrowerResidencyType='Current']"
```

which works when I put it in Altova XML Spy and gives me a result.

But when I use it directly as it is `Xelement.XPathSelectElement(XPath)`, it does not work, but what works is `Xelement.XPathSelectElement(collective, nameSpaceManager)` where collective is namesspace prefix (say named "ns") plus my XPath string.

But the problem is I have to change XPath string to something like this

```
"(//ns:DEAL_SETS/ns:DEAL_SET/ns:DEALS/ns:DEAL/ns:PARTIES/ns:PARTY[ns:ROLES/
    ns:ROLE/ns:ROLE_DETAIL/ns:PartyRoleType='Borrower'])[(ns:ROLES/
        ns:PARTY_ROLE_IDENTIFIERS/ns:PARTY_ROLE_IDENTIFIER/
            ns:PartyRoleIdentifier='1' or position() = 1)]/ns:ROLES/
                ns:ROLE/ns:BORROWER/ns:RESIDENCES/ns:RESIDENCE/
                    ns:ADDRESS/ns:PostalCode[../../ns:RESIDENCE_DETAIL/
                        ns:BorrowerResidencyType='Current']"
```

Is there any way to avoid having to put the namespace prefix (`ns:`) at each node.

Sorry for not posting the sample xml earlier,you may replicate the Party tag and its elements and fill up with false data, PartyRoleType gives me what party it is could be borrower,appraiser etc partyroleidentifier gives me a way to differentiate between two party with same partyroletypes for eg there could be 2 borrowers,the partyroleidentifier differentiates them as 1 and 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MESSAGE xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xxxxReferenceModelIdentifier="3.0.0.263.12" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/schemas C:\Subversion\xxx_3_0.xsd">
 <DEAL_SETS>
    <DEAL_SET>
      <DEALS>
        <DEAL>
          <PARTIES>
            <PARTY>
              <ROLES>
                <ROLE>
                  <PARTY_ROLE_IDENTIFIERS>
                     <PARTY_ROLE_IDENTIFIER>
                       <PartyRoleIdentifier>1</PartyRoleIdentifier>
                     </PARTY_ROLE_IDENTIFIER>
                  </PARTY_ROLE_IDENTIIERS>
                  <BORROWER>
                    <RESIDENCES>
                      <RESIDENCE>
                        <ADDRESS>
                        <PostalCode>56236</PostalCode>
                        </ADDRESS>
                      </RESIDENCE>
                    </RESIDENCES>
                  </BORROWER>
                  <ROLE_DETAIL>
                    <PartyRoleType>Borrower</PartyRoleType>
                  </ROLE_DETAIL>
                </ROLE>
              </ROLES>
            </PARTY>
          </PARTIES>
        </DEAL>
      </DEALS>
    </DEAL_SET>
  </DEAL_SETS>
</MESSAGE>
```

Comment: A correct answer (without using "guess mode") is impossible, because you haven't provided the XML document. Please, edit the question and provide a complete XML document (but the smallest possible) and a complete XPath expression(s) (but the smallest possible) that reproduce the problem.

Comment: hi Dimitre i have posted the sample xml now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>According to the MSDN documentation, when you call [AddNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace.aspx) for your namespace manager, you can use `String.Empty` as the prefix for your namespace URI.  That should enable you to do an XPath expression without all those `ns:` prefixes.</strike>

**Update**:

OK, I remember encountering this issue before.  The behavior of empty namespace prefixes in XPath expressions is not consistent with the rest of the .NET XML suite.  There is some evidence that some Microsoft folks are aware of the issue.  See [this forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/599b9cf7-8faf-4c82-9d31-30b3e688cba4).  I'll look for a while more for solutions, but I'm thinking that you'll have to make do with using namespace prefixes.

**Update 2**:

Feel free to vote on this [Microsoft Connect Bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/714021/empty-namespace-prefix-does-not-work-as-expected-with-xpath) that I've just created.  I see that they have closed similar bugs in the past, but none of them focused on *usability* concerns before.  Maybe we'll get some traction with more votes.

**Update 3**:

Just some clarifications, my filed bug is not and never was about *compliance with XPath standards*, but rather about usability.  No matter the standards, users need a way to make XPath queries with namespaced XML more succinct, and that is currently not supported.  As far as standards support goes, XSLT 2.0 has a way to do XPath 2.0 with empty namespace prefixes associated with a namespace URI, and XMLSpy has that capability as well.  [The MSDN documentation claims that .NET has XPath 2.0 support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but the veracity of that claim is under dispute.  One could argue that .NET is properly implementing XPath 1.0 by disallowing the modification of what an empty prefix represents.

Comment: Hi Jacob, string.Empty does not work it returns a null output, I have also tried "" same result

Comment: Thanks jacob for your help, i just voted as per your suggestion

Comment: @_Jacob: This answer is wrong and I have downvoted it. Please, learn about the ways to select elements that are in a default namespace -- a simple search will find many good answers.

Comment: @Dimitre: I have not accepted Jacobs String.Empty as the correct answer but i have accepted that there is no way around adding any kind of prefix to the nodes(which he talks about in Update). Basically i did not want to add any kind of prefix to my xpath nodes if all of them comply to the same default namespace.

Comment: @user602182: Jacob is labeling as "bug" and the correct behavior of any compliant XPath engine. This is both wrong and harmful, as it may confuse the non-expert user into thinking that any compliant XPath engine is buggy. As for avoiding prefixes, my Solution 2. is just that. I strongly recommend that you cancel your acceptance of an obviously wrong and harmful answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, if you can reference your source saying that an XPath processor *must* interpret empty prefixes as empty namespaces, please cite.

Comment: @_Jacob: Before filing a "bug" it is best to become educated in the subject. What you are labeling as "bug" is actually the correct behavior any compliant XPath engine must have as per the W3C XPath specification: "*if the QName does not have a prefix, then the namespace URI is null".*" See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests

Comment: @user602182: So, you have voted for a "bug" that actually is correct behavior as per W3C spec ... :)

Comment: That's the spec for XPath 1.0.  .NET supports XPath 2.0, which states "An unprefixed QName, when used as a name test on an axis whose principal node kind is element, has the namespace URI of the default element/type namespace in the expression context; otherwise, it has no namespace URI."  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/

Comment: @Jacob: Your statement that ".NET supports XPath 2.0" is not true! Also, you don't understandthe quoted text -- it refers to the expression context -- and this has nothing to do with a default namespace in any XML document.

Comment: "The System.Xml.XPath namespace contains the classes that define a cursor model for navigating and editing XML information items as instances of the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model."  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath(v=VS.100).aspx.  And keeping in mind that the XSLT 2.0 document I referred to earlier *explicitly* states that it can specify a URI for a blank prefix has to make you wonder: does XSLT 2.0 *require a non-conformant XPath 2.0?*

Comment: OK, enough extended discussion for me.  Your incorrect statements are taking too much time to disprove.  Please research your statements before posting them.

Comment: @Jacob: This statement from the MSDN documentation is not true. The easiest way to verify this is by trying to evaluate a simple XPath 2.0 expression, like: `(1,2,3)[2]` . Please, do try and report your findings. :)

Comment: Ok guys calm down, all i wanted from this question was whether there is a work around the prefix thing, to which both of you have replied "No" and i tend to agree with that and that's why i have accepted Jacob's answer.Now I don't know much about standards like you both and i believe both of you are very capable programmers, and am not putting any one down, so if any of you guys think so I am sorry, but the fact of the matter is there is no workaround(you end up adding something to the node always). Once again thank you both for your kind help.

Comment: @user602182: The accepted answer starts with: "*According to the MSDN documentation, when you call AddNamespace for your namespace manager, you can use String.Empty as the prefix for your namespace URI. That should enable you to do an XPath expression without all those ns: prefixes.*" And this suggestion is completely wrong. Next further down in the accepting answer, the compliant behavior is called a "bug" and the author is asking the readers to vote for this bug: "*Feel free to vote on this Microsoft Connect Bug that I've just created.*". The irony is that this answer is accepted.

Comment: @Jacob: Re: "No matter the standards": The standards are what matters and what defines compliance/correctness. The W3C standards are the only normative source about XPath 1.0. In your "bug" submitted to Microsoft Connect you state: "Feel free to change this to a feature request, but to me, this is a bug because the code does not work in an intuitively obvious or consistent way". That some people don't find a product intuitive isn't a bug. A bug is behavior that contradicts the product requirements. The XPath 1.0 reqs are the W3C XPath 1.0 spec and this "bug" is actually a requirement ... :)

Comment: @Jacob: So, what you are asking as a "fix", would be a bug, if implemented.

Comment: I don't think compliance with the "XPath 2.0 Data Model", which MSDN claims .NET has, is the same thing as compliance with XPath 2.0. If you look at the abstract for [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/), you'll see that XPath 2.0 is an expression language that allows the processsing of values conforming to the XPath 2.0 Data Model. The Introduction says that the XPath 2.0 spec also depends on XPath 2.0 Formal Semantics and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators. MSDN could accurately claim XPath 2.0 Data Model compliance without needing to be compliant with XPath 2.0 as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

**The currently accepted answer is wrong**  !

Any compliant XPath processor interprets a non-prefixed name to belong to "no-namespace".

**This is the biggest FAQ in XPath**:

There is no way in XPath to select elements in a default namespace, by using their un-prefixed name.

The reason is that XPath considers any unprefixed name to reside in "no namespave" and it is looking to find elements with such name that are in "no namespace" Such elements aren't found and selected, because all elements are in a non-empty, default namespace.

**Here is a precise quote from the [W3C XPath 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests)**:

> "*if the QName does not have a prefix, then the namespace URI is null*".

**There are two main solutions:**

1. Using the XPath-related  API available in your programming language, register an association between the default namespace and a string prefix (lets say `"x"`). Then modify your wxpression and replace anyunprefixed `someElementName` with `x:someElementName`. In .NET, to register the association, an `XmlNamespaceManager` object typically has to be created, and its `AddNamespace()` method needs to be used for registering the association. Then, when calling the XPath-selecting method, the XmlNamespaceManager instance is passed as an additional argument.
2. If one wants to avoid registering the default namespace, one workaround is, instead of:

..

```
/a/b/c
```

to use:

```
/*[name()='a']/*[name()='b']/*[name()='c']
```

Comment: `Any compliant XPath processor interprets a non-prefixed name to belong to "no-namespace".`  Cite please!  Compliant XSLT 2.0 processors, for example, have a way to associate non-prefixed nodes with a non-empty namespace using the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames.

Comment: @Jacob: Your statement that ".NET supports XPath 2.0" is not true! Also, you don't understandthe quoted text -- it refers to the expression context -- and this has nothing to do with a default namespace in any XML document. On the contrary, "expression context" is exactly the information that could be provided by what in .NET is the XmlNamespaceManager object. This becomes part of the so called "static context" for the evaluation of the XPath expression.

Comment: @Jacob: The question is for .NET and C# and not about evaluation of XPath expressions inside an XSLT 2.0 processors. In .NET the way to create XPath expression context namespace binding information is exactly by using an XmlNamespaceManager object or any object implementing `IXmlNamespaceResolver` -- and the question was can unprefixed names that are in a default namespace be evaluated correctly in .NET using `Xelement.XPathSelectElement()` without such additional binding data. The answer is negative. Your answer is completely wrong! Consider correcting or deleting this wrong/misleading answer

Comment: The reason why comformant XSLT 2.0 processors are compliant XPath 2.0 processors is because they set the expression context with `xpath-default-namespace`.  Just because .NET doesn't provide the capability to do so through `XmlNamespaceManager` has nothing to do with compliance.  XSLT 2.0 is just one specification that uses the XPath 2.0 feature that enables you to associate empty namespace prefixes with a specific namespace URI.  .NET could choose to do the same.

Comment: Once again: .NET doesn't implement XPath 2.0. The way to provide namespace binding information into the expression evaluation context in .Net is via an object that implements the `IXmlNamespaceResolver` interface, such as `XmlNamespaceManager`. Even in this case, the associated prefix cannot be empty (for XPath 1.0, which is what .NET implements). Thus, the correct answer to the OP's question is that it isn't possible in .NET or in any compliant XPath 1.0 implementation to select unprefixed names that are in a default namespace. Thus your answer is wrong. Please, consider deleting it.

Comment: @Jacob: Re: "NET could choose to do the same"... Implementing this in any XPath 1.0 engine makes it automatically non-compliant. Therefore, .NET cannot choose to have a non-compliant XPath 1.0 engine. *If* and *when* it is decided to implement XPath 2.0 in .NET, then this could be a potential feature. To summarize, what your answer labels as "bug" is true compliance to the W3C XPath 1.0 specification. Please, be honest and delete the disinformation.

Comment: I see you continue to delete answers considered unfavourable by the community only to re-post them again in a new answer. Please can you stop doing that.

Comment: @Kev: In case you really care about the community you can contact me via email so that we could discuss your concerns.